# How to add reset button to forms?

Tags: 7, forms

I've been researching this matter for a while with no clear answer yet.
So, here are a few questions ...

1. I'm **assuming** (correct me if I'm wrong) that Drupal 7 doesn't support reset buttons. It appears, according to the form API (as discussed in Pro Drupal 7 Development), that all the buttons (input type="submit", button, and image_button) are by default submit buttons. There doesn't appear to be a way to override the defaults either.

   So, if I wanted to add functionality to my forms for my users to clear forms (if they choose), would I have to create a module?
2. Would I be able to pull this off by using the **general button type** with **executes_submit_callback** set to **false** and by adding some type of Ajax function to the mousedown event?

** EDIT: I added the following to my hook_form_alter() **

```
$form['reset'] = array(
'#input' => TRUE,
'#name' => 'reset',
'#button_type' => 'reset',
'#executes_submit_callback' => FALSE,
'#limit_validation_errors' => TRUE,
'#process' => '',
'#theme_wrappers' => array('button'),
);
```

I got the following error message & warning:

> Notice: Undefined index: #type in _form_builder_handle_input_element() (line 1949 of /var/www/vhosts/lae/drupal-7.11/includes/form.inc).
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in form_builder() (line 1763 of /var/www/vhosts/lae/drupal-7.11/includes/form.inc).

Is there a way to add the "reset" button type to the types of buttons without crashing the entire form.inc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My preferred way to do this is.

Add the button to your form like so:

```
$form['options']['reset'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Reset'),
  '#submit' => array('MY_MODULE_FORM_ID_reset'),
);
```

Then create the reset function like so:

```
function MY_MODULE_FORM_ID_reset($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['rebuild'] = FALSE;
}
```

No Javascript, no markup.

Answer (score 6):

Don't know of support in Form API for a reset button, but simple enough to add a form alter to add one.

```
MYMODULE_form_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['resetbutton'] = array(
    '#markup' => '<button type="reset"/>',
    '#weight' => 1000
  );
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: That was an awesome answer!!!!

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to add that reset button to the actions div?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out: `$form['actions']['reset'] = array('#markup' => '<input id="reset" type="reset" value="reset" />', '#weight' => 1000);`

Comment: What is weird, however, is that after I hit SUBMIT on my form, the reset button no longer works.  It works if a user has not hit the SUBMIT button.  Weird

Comment: @user785179 form reset button resets the form fields to their original values, so after submit those fields will have `value="something"`, and that value will be restored. **Reset does not blank all fields**.

Answer (score 2):

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

switch ($form_id) { 

case 'myform':
  $form['buttons']['reset_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#value' => '<input class="form-button" value="Reset" type="reset">',
    '#weight' => 2000,
  );
  break;
 }
 return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is 100% working:

```
$form['reset'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => '<input type="reset" value="Reset All Values" class="form-submit">',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually I give reset hyperlink which is pointing to current page URL using Markup form type.

When ever we click this link, it will refresh the page & will reset all the form elements. Else using javascript / Jquery we can reset the form elements by providing specific CSS Class / ID to that link.

Answer (score 0):

None of the previous answers worked in the case I've been facing (`views_exposed_form` with [BEF](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) and ajax enabled). I had set up the reset button from BEF, but it was working only for one of my two views displays, whatever I tried...

I purpose another approach, in case it could help.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function moduleName_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

  if (isset($form_state['view']->current_display) && 'some_display' == $form_state['view']->current_display ) {

    $submit_btn_id = $form['submit']['#id'];
    if (!empty($submit_btn_id) && !empty($form['reset'])) {
      //avoid the know issue redirecting views resets to /node
      $form['#action'] = '/' . $_GET['q'];
      // Add own reset button
      $form['submit']['#suffix'] = '<input type="reset" onclick="javascript:jQuery(this.form).clearForm();jQuery(this.form).find(\'#' . $submit_btn_id . '\').trigger(\'click\');return false;">' . t('Reset') . '</input>';
      $form['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'my-views-filter-submit';
      // Remove the original RESET button.
      unset($form['reset']);
    }
  }
}
```

About the issue redirecting views resets to `/node`... `onclick="history.go(0)`; is an alternative.

This was inspired by Julian blog [add ajaxified reset button for views exposed filters](http://julian.pustkuchen.com/en/drupal-7-views-3-add-ajaxified-reset-button-views-exposed-filters) but I had to adapt it substantially.

Answer (score -2):

This is my way to add Reset button, hope you like it :D

```
$form['reset'] = array(
'#markup'   => '<input type="reset" class="form-submit" />',
'#title'    => 'Reset',
);
```

Comment: No - never do this. Always use the Form API.